# Does jQuery select2 plug-in work with dynamically created textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery select2 search box works fine with input elements, but doesn't work with dynamically created textbox elements.

Please, if anyone has any idea why, please let me know:

```
<input class="select2-offscreen itemid"
       type="text"
       name="itemid"
       id="itemid[]"
       style="width:100px; left:297.5px !important; top:863px !important; float:left !important"
       tabindex="-1"
       onchange="createItem(this);">`
```

select2 works fine with the input tag above, but when I dynamically create a row in a table, it doesn't:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var item = document.createElement("input");
item.type = "text";
item.name="itemid";
item.id="itemid[]";
item.className="select2-offscreen";
item.style="width:100px"; 
cell1.appendChild(item);
```

Comment: If it's working for the `input`, post that code here and post HTML of the textboxes that are rendered dynamically!

Comment: You have to instantiate select2 after that dynamic creation. IE: $("#itemid").select2();

Comment: where i need to call select2() method in javascript code

Comment: After appendChild(item);